# Finding triplicates in 4 lists

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm trying to find, given 4 arrays of N strings, a string that is common to at least 3 of the arrays in O(N*log(N)) time, and if it exists return the lexicographically first string.

What I tried was creating an array of size 4*N and adding items from the 4 arrays to it while removing the duplicates. Then I did a Quick sort on the big array to find the first eventual triplicate.

Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: Can the string appear twice in the same list? How do you count it then?

Comment: Yes the string can appear many times in the same list, but the task is to find strings common to at least 3 different lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in O(n log n), with constant extra space. It's a standard [k-way merge problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Ideal_Merge), after sorting the individual lists. If the individual lists can contain duplicates, then you'll need to remove the duplicates during the sorting.

So, assuming you have `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, and `list4`:

```
Sort the individual lists, removing duplicates
Create a priority queue (min-heap) of length 4
Add the first item from each list to the heap
last-key = ""
last-key-count = 0
while not done
    remove the smallest item from the min-heap
    add to the heap the next item from the list that contained the item you just removed.
    if the item matches last-key
        increment last-key-count
        if last-key-count == 3 then
            output last-key
            exit done
        else
            last-key-count = 1
            last-key = item key
end while
// if you get here, there was no triplicate item
```

An alternate way to do this is to combine all the lists into a single list, then sort it. You can then go through it sequentially to find the first triplicate. Again, if the individual lists can contain duplicates, you should remove them before you combine the lists.

```
combined = list1.concat(list2.concat(list3.concat(list4)))
last-key = ""
last-key-count = 0
for i = 0 to combined.length-1
    if combined[i] == last-key
        last-key-count++
        if last-key-count == 3
            exit done
        else
            last-key = combined[i]
            last-key-count = 1
end for
// if you get here, no triplicate was found
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we have 4 arrays of N strings, where N = 5. My approach to get all triplicates is:

1. Get the **1st** string of the **1st** array and add it in a Map< String, Set< Integer > > with the array number in the Set (I'm using a Hash because insertion and search are O(1));
2. Get the **1st** string of the **2nd** array and add it in a Map< String, Set< Integer > > with the array number in the Set;
3. Repeat step 2, but using 3rd and 4th arrays instead of 2nd;
4. Repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 but using the **2nd** string instead of 1st;
5. Repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 but using the **3nd** string instead of 1st;
6. Etc.

In the worst case, we will have N*4 comparisons, O(N*log(N)).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arr = { 
                { "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "zzz", "aaa" }, 
                { "ttt", "bbb", "ddd", "iii", "aaa" },
                { "sss", "kkk", "uuu", "rrr", "zzz" }, 
                { "iii", "zzz", "lll", "hhh", "aaa" }};

        List<String> triplicates = findTriplicates(arr);

        Collections.sort(triplicates);

        for (String word : triplicates)
            System.out.println(word);
    }

    public static List<String> findTriplicates(String[][] arr) {
        Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
        List<String> triplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
        final int N = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                String str = arr[j][i];
                if (map.containsKey(str)) {
                    map.get(str).add(j);
                    if (map.get(str).size() == 3)
                        triplicates.add(str);
                } else {
                    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
                    set.add(j);
                    map.put(str, set);
                }
            }
        }
        return triplicates;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aaa
zzz
```

Comment: "*HashMap because insertion and search are O(1)*" I would be very careful with that one.

Comment: Sure, @luk32. It depends on Java's Hash Function. Even though the worst case could be O(N), what is almost impossible,  the average is O(1). So let's trust it. =)

Comment: You talk about insertion. Not hash. I doubt anyone can hash a string in `O(1)`. Insertion should be `O(1)` once hash is known, unless rehashing occurs, which sure by design should be not too often, on that I agree of course. Btw. I think your code gives wrong code for the following input: `String[][] arr = { { "xxx", "hhh", "rrr", "zzz", "aaa" }, { "ttt", "bbb", "ddd", "iii", "aaa" }, { "sss", "kkk", "uuu", "rrr", "zzz" }, { "iii", "zzz", "lll", "hhh", "aaa" } };`. I think it should be `aaa`. Tested here: https://ideone.com/wDvUT4

Comment: I think it should be "zzz", because it's in the last position of the third array. And "aaa" is in the last position of the fourth array. So the third "zzz" will be found first.

Comment: 1. But OP wants the 1st **lexicographically** string. I think the point is from all the triplets and quadruplets to choose the lowest **lexicographically**. Not just the 1st one you will find. "*the task is to find strings common to at least 3 different lists*". I might have misunderstood this.

Comment: 2. I don't have much doubts. Yes, the operations on hash table are O(1), but remember what you are counting here - hash operations. And hashing strings is not free. One should remember that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode() says "*From Java 1.2, java.lang.String class implements its hashCode() using a product sum algorithm over the entire text of the string.*" - it's `O(n)` (size of string). Even your link mentions in "Drawbacks" section that hashing might be expensive.

Comment: Man, what's your problem? Do you know someone that use Java 1.2?

Comment: But he said "to find the first eventual triplicate" as well. Besides that, it's very easy to change the code. So let him decide if my answer is enough or if he needs something else.

Comment: Now the program will give you a sorted list as result =)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you don't care about the constant factors this can be done in `O(N)` where `N` is the size of strings. It is important to distinguish number of strings vs their total size for practical purposes. (At the end I propose an alternative version which is `O(N log N)` where `N` is number of string comparisons.

You need one map `string -> int` for `count`, and one temporary `already_counted` map `string -> bool`. The latter one is basically a set. Important thing is to use unordered/hash versions of the associative containers, to avoid `log` factors.

For each array, for each element, you check whether the current element is in `already_counted` set. If not, do `count[current_string] ++`. Before going over to the next array empty the `already_counted` set.

Now you basically need a min search. Go over each element of `count` and if an element has value 3 or more, then compare the key associated with it, to your current `min`. Voilà. `min` is the lowest string with 3 or more occurences.

You don't need the `N log N` factor, because you do not need all the triplets, so no sorting or ordered data structures are needed. **You have `O(3*N)`** (again `N` is the total size of all string). This is an over estimation, later I give more detailed estimation.

Now, **the caveat** is that this method is based on string hashing, which is `O(S)`, where `S` is the size of string. Twice, to deal with per-array repetitions. **So, alternatively,** might be faster, at least in c++ implementation, to actually use ordered versions of the containers. There are two reasons for this:

1. Comparing strings might be faster then hashing them. If the strings are different, then you will get a result of a comparison relatively fast, whereas with hashing you *always* go over whole string, and hashing quite more complicated.
2. They are contiguous in memory - cache friendly.
3. Hashing also has a problem with rehashing, etc. etc.

If the number of strings is not large, or if their size is very big, I would place my bet on the ordered versions. Also, if you have ordered `count` you get an edge in finding the least element because it's the 1st with `count > 3`, though in worst case you will get tons of `a*` with count `1` and `z` with 3.

So, to sum all of it up, if we call `n` the number of string comparisons, and `N` the number of string hashes.

1. Hash-based method is `O(2 N + n)` and with some trickery you can bring down constant factor by 1, e.g. reusing hash for `count` and the `already_checked`.\, or combining both data structures for example via [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). So you would get `O(N + n)`.
2. Pure string comparison based method would be `O(2 n log n + n)`. Maybe somehow it would be possible to easily use hinting to drop the constant, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in O(N) using [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

You loop 4 lists one by one, for each list you insert the strings into the Trie.

When you inserting a string **s** of list **L**,  increase the counter **only if** there is string **s** in previous lists. Update the answer if the counter >= 3 and is lexicographically smaller than the current answer.

Here is a sample C++ code, you can input 4 list of string, each contains 5 string to test it.
http://ideone.com/fTmKgJ

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<string>> lists;
string ans = "";

struct TrieNode
{
    TrieNode* l[128];
    int n;

    TrieNode()
    {
        memset(l, 0, sizeof(TrieNode*) * 128);
        n = 0;
    }
} *root = new TrieNode();

void add(string s, int listID)
{
    TrieNode* p = root;
    for (auto x: s)
    {
        if (!p->l[x]) p->l[x] = new TrieNode();
        p = p->l[x];
    }
    p->n |= (1<<listID);
    if(__builtin_popcount(p->n) >= 3 && (ans == "" || s < ans)) ans = s;
}

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        string s;
        vector<string> v;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            cin >> s;
            v.push_back(s); 
        } 
        lists.push_back(v);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        for(auto s: lists[i]){
            add(s, i);
        }
    }
    if(ans == "") cout << "NO ANSWER" << endl;
    else cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/d4rOlu here's a more c++-like implementation. It's more standard, and more readable I guess. However, your implementation differs from the description: "*When you inserting a string s of list L, increase the counter only if there is string s in previous lists.*" this is not happening, you use a *bitmap* to store which list does the item belong to, then count the number of bits and update the answer. That is a nice spin on the answer though. I'd also think about using standard `map<char, TrieNode>` for TrieNode storage. It should be fast and save lots of space.

Comment: "Update the counter" is a high level way to describe it, I use a bitmap for easier implementation. One can implement it using any other way, like store a 4-boolean size array  used[4]  in each node, set used[listID] = true and only count how many true value in the array.  As long as the number "4" is given, whatever implementation should yield constant time I guess.

Comment: @luk32 But yes, your code is way more like a C++ implementation, that's beautiful I should say.

Comment: I think "update the counter conditionally" is semantically different. It's more how I proposed things. There is a `counter` variable, and an `if`. You retain more information, don't have a condition, and sum up bits to get the count, you don't have a counter. It does serve the same purpose, but it is not the same thing. I actually like this more than an additional set to deal with duplicates. Thanks for compliment, I wasn't trying to "correct" your answer, I liked it, so I just decided to make it more modern c++ as an exercise and a bit more readable, for the answer purposes. Cheers.